# How to get md5sum of a file inside a zip, without extracting the zip

Tags: md5, md5sum, md5-file

Is there any way to get the `md5sum` of a file inside a zip file, without extracting the `zip` ?. 
I have a `zip` file containing directories `plugins`, `p2` and `features` where `plugins` directory contains lot of `jar` files. How can I get the `md5sum` of a given `jar` file inside the `plugins` directory ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone suggested the usage of Java Streams, [Example of md5 hashes without unpacking a zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267483/md5-hash-for-zip-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MD5 hash for zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267483/md5-hash-for-zip-files)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the md5sum using below command

```
unzip -Z1 archive.zip | while read -r file; do
    echo -n "$file: "
    unzip -p archive.zip "$file" | md5sum
done
```

Comment: See title of the question: "....without extracting the zip"

Comment: @Luuk Yes, the above command will print the MD5SUM with File Path of the provided archive.zip without extracting the zip, Can you try one time and comment?

Let you explain the parameter which i used in above command,

-Z --> To get Zip info and 1 will provide the filenames ONLY, one per line

-p --> extract files to pipe, no messages

Comment: Well, it seems to be doing what is expected, but technically speaking you are extracting the zip...